# odoo domain force based on date field not working?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I am using odoo11. I added a group for particular users and added this rule

```
<record id="test_records" model="ir.rule">
            <field name="name">test</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="crm.model_crm_lead"/>
            <field name="global" eval="False"/>
            <field name="domain_force">[('create_date', '>=', user.ind_creation_date)]</field>
            <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('test_module.test_group'))]"/>
</record>
```

I added the custom date field ind_creation_date in res_users model.

my goal is to show the **crm_lead** records, that **create_date** of crm_lead records that greater than or equal to **res_users's ind_creation_date**.

there is no error but it does not show records properly . I think **domain_force** not worked here ,I manually enter date there it works

Comment: Your code looks OK. What do you mean by "it does not show records properly", is any record whose create date is before the custom date in user model shown?
There will be a lot of other record rules for crm_lead. Check all the rules and your user configuration make sure the values are shown correctly. If not please specify how it is different from your expectation.

Comment: Check Settings/ Technical/  Security/ Record Rules

Comment: @Amal:Thanks for comment.I get solution I changes the field type to datetime.create date is date time field . so i changed the ind_creation_date field to datetime. that time it works correctly

Comment: Try `<field name="domain_force">[('create_date', '>=', user.ind_creation_date)]</field>` it's also work but make sure `ind_creation_date` field is `fields.Date()` instead of `fields.Datetime()`.